# precompile both minified and un-minified versions of javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, minify

I'd like to provide both the minified and un-minified versions of my javascript assets on a Ruby on Rails production environment.

Ideally the the cache buster digest would still exist so the files would look like this:

- application-067137a1719812a24eb8a2fd9d1c1ee2.js
- application-067137a1719812a24eb8a2fd9d1c1ee2.min.js

The position of the .min doesn't matter too much.

My config in environments/production.rb uses ufligier:

```
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
```

Comment: Just curious, why do you want that behaviour?

Comment: @Pigueiras good question, it is for debugging in production. We capture exceptions and report the line and column number. Obviously a minified js is hard to debug with as line number wouldn't normally be in the single digits and column would be somewhere in the hundreds.

Our intentions are to turn on or off minification with an environment variable when we want to investigate a reoccurring error.

Comment: Kind of along the same lines of the question above. Is there a way to segregate the minification? IE say if you app is not mature but you only wanted the vendor files to be minified.